# Сравнение двух матриц переходов

Tags: python, pandas, матрицы, анализ-данных, линейная-алгебра

Есть текст: "аааааааааа аааааааааа аааааааааа аааааааааа аааааааааа аааааааааа аааааааааа аааааааааа аааааааааа аааааааааа вввввввввв вввввввввв вввввввввв вввввввввв вввввввввв вввввввввв вввввввввв вввввввввв вввввввввв вввввввввв".

Составляю матрицу переходов, которая имеет вид (далее именую - Исходная матрица):

```
state2         а         в        а         аа        в         вв
state1                                                            
 а      0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.046296  0.000000  0.000000
 в      0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.046296
а       0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.037037  0.000000  0.009259
аа      0.046296  0.000000  0.046296  0.324074  0.000000  0.000000
в       0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.037037
вв      0.000000  0.046296  0.000000  0.000000  0.037037  0.324074
```

Тестируемые матрицы:

```
state2         а         в        а         аа        в         вв
state1                                                            
 а      0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.046296  0.000000  0.000000
 в      0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.046296
а       0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.009259  0.000000  0.037037
аа      0.018519  0.018519  0.046296  0.287037  0.000000  0.000000
в       0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.018519  0.000000  0.018519
вв      0.027778  0.027778  0.000000  0.000000  0.037037  0.361111
```

---

```
state2         в         г        в         вв       г         гг
state1                                                           
 в      0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.037736  0.00000  0.000000
 г      0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.00000  0.056604
в       0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.028302  0.00000  0.000000
вв      0.018868  0.047170  0.028302  0.377358  0.00000  0.000000
г       0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.037736  0.00000  0.009434
гг      0.018868  0.009434  0.000000  0.000000  0.04717  0.283019
```

Здесь учитываются не только пары букв 'вв', 'aa', но также одиночные буквы с пробелом ' а', 'а '.
Предположим, что у меня есть еще несколько подобных матриц созданных из других строк, например: "авававав ааа ввввв ава в ав ав ав авававааааа аааааааа вввввв" и т.д., назовем их матрицы для тестирования.

Вопрос, как найти одну из тестируемых матриц более "схожую" с исходной матрицей?

Не знаю как объяснить, но на выходе хотелось бы получить: 1 (тестируемая) матрица соответствует исходной на 30 %, 2 соответствует исходной на 15%. Если такое возможно. Или есть другие варианты.

Comment: что значит "схожая"? идентичная, или есть какие-то отличия?

Comment: Все что я смог понять из сформулированного вами вопроса это только то, что у вас есть текст. Как вы получаете "матрицу переходов"? Имеет ли ваша "матрица переходов" какое-либо отношение к [матрице переходов из линейной алгебры](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0) и если имеет, то почему значения дуюлируются (например `a` и `в` - дублируются в столбцах и строках)?? Каков у вас критерий схожести? Можете привести в вопросе небольшиие примеры данных (несколько матриц) и результат, который вы хотите получить?

Comment: Если Вы имеете в виду, что под "идентичными", понимаются те матрицы, где все элементы одной матрицы равны элементам другой, то здесь сложнее. К примеру есть исходная матрица для простоты запишем ее как [1, 2, 3], и есть несколько тестируемым матриц [2,1,3], [3,1,2]. Вопрос заключается в том как определить какая из тестируемых матриц ближе к исходной матрице. В терминологии разбираюсь плохо. Что если есть наводящие вопросы, постараюсь объяснить.

Comment: я бы посоветовал вам обратить внимание на "косинусное сходство", но пока непонятно как выглядит вторая матрица, с которой вы хотите сравнивать первую... Косинусное расстояние - метрика схожести многомерных векторов, НО вектора можно сравнивать только в том случае если они принадлежат единому векторному пространству, т.е. если у матриц совпадают имена столбцов

Comment: Основная идея. Если посмотреть на матрицу, то видим что на пересечении вв (строка) и вв (столбец) дает нам 0.324074, что значит что вероятность появления после вв  вв  равно 0.324074.

Comment: Если возьмем другой текст, то вероятность там будет другой, а в третьем тексте она будет равна 0.

Comment: В окончательном варианте виде матрицы будут иметь вид общий вид, где будут совпадать имена строк и столбцов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю сначала привести все матрицы к единому векторному пространству (одинаковый набор столбцов), а потом посчитать косинусную схожесть полученных матриц.

Примеры входных данных (NOTE: в Pandas неудобно работать со столбцами, наимеование которых имеют пробелы в начале или в конце):

```
In [43]: a
Out[43]:
          space_а   space_в   а_space        аа   в_space        вв
space_а  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.046296  0.000000  0.000000
space_в  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.046296
а_space  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.009259  0.000000  0.037037
аа       0.018519  0.018519  0.046296  0.287037  0.000000  0.000000
в_space  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.018519  0.000000  0.018519
вв       0.027778  0.027778  0.000000  0.000000  0.037037  0.361111

In [44]: b
Out[44]:
          space_в   space_г   в_space        вв  г_space        гг
space_в  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.037736  0.00000  0.000000
space_г  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.00000  0.056604
space_в  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.028302  0.00000  0.000000
вв       0.018868  0.047170  0.028302  0.377358  0.00000  0.000000
г_space  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.037736  0.00000  0.009434
гг       0.018868  0.009434  0.000000  0.000000  0.04717  0.283019
```

Вариант решения:

```
In [48]: a1 = a.assign(**dict.fromkeys(b.columns.difference(a.columns), 0)).sort_index(axis="columns")

In [49]: b1 = b.assign(**dict.fromkeys(a.columns.difference(b.columns), 0)).sort_index(axis="columns")
```

получили матрицы в едином векторном пространстве:

```
In [50]: a1
Out[50]:
          space_а   space_в  space_г   а_space        аа   в_space        вв  г_space  гг
space_а  0.000000  0.000000        0  0.000000  0.046296  0.000000  0.000000        0   0
space_в  0.000000  0.000000        0  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.046296        0   0
а_space  0.000000  0.000000        0  0.000000  0.009259  0.000000  0.037037        0   0
аа       0.018519  0.018519        0  0.046296  0.287037  0.000000  0.000000        0   0
в_space  0.000000  0.000000        0  0.000000  0.018519  0.000000  0.018519        0   0
вв       0.027778  0.027778        0  0.000000  0.000000  0.037037  0.361111        0   0

In [51]: b1
Out[51]:
         space_а   space_в   space_г  а_space  аа   в_space        вв  г_space        гг
space_в        0  0.000000  0.000000        0   0  0.000000  0.037736  0.00000  0.000000
space_г        0  0.000000  0.000000        0   0  0.000000  0.000000  0.00000  0.056604
space_в        0  0.000000  0.000000        0   0  0.000000  0.028302  0.00000  0.000000
вв             0  0.018868  0.047170        0   0  0.028302  0.377358  0.00000  0.000000
г_space        0  0.000000  0.000000        0   0  0.000000  0.037736  0.00000  0.009434
гг             0  0.018868  0.009434        0   0  0.000000  0.000000  0.04717  0.283019
```

теперерь их можно сравнить:

```
In [52]: from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

In [53]: cs = cosine_similarity(a1, b1)
```

результат:

```
In [54]: cs
Out[54]:
array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [1.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.9883323 , 0.9701425 , 0.        ],
       [0.97014404, 0.        , 0.97014404, 0.95882469, 0.94117797, 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.0031349 , 0.        , 0.00416043],
       [0.70710678, 0.        , 0.70710678, 0.69885647, 0.68599434, 0.        ],
       [0.98900701, 0.        , 0.98900701, 0.98874614, 0.95947774, 0.00498942]])
```

Идея косинусной схожести в измерении косинуса угла между двумя векторами (векторы могут быть многомерными). Как известно из курса школьной тригонометрии, косинус угла `0 градусов` равен `1`, а для угла `90 градусов` - `0`. Т.е. вектора, заданные координатами (в векторном или матричном виде) и такие, что у них совпадают все координаты дадут косинусное сходство - `1`, а два вектора, у которых нет ни одного совпадения дадут косинусное сходство - `0`. Чем больше сходство тем ближе косинусное сходство к единице, чем меньше - ближе к нулю.

PS если сравнивать много векторов/матриц, то сначала необходимо привести к единому векторному пространству **все** вектора.

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую.